# Do not let the variable display the value

Tags: php, variables

The following code gets automatically executed and displays the value of it:

```
$date_up = ceil(the_field('jahr') / 10) * 10;
```

I do NOT want to display it. I only want to save it in a variable.

I already tried to declare it as a string with this code:

```
$date_up = settype(ceil(the_field('jahr') / 10) * 10, 'string');
```

But that is not going to work, since the first parameter needs to be a variable. Funny but that is exactly what I want ... just a simple variable that is doing nothing. Any solutions?

Comment: *"The following code gets automatically executed and displays the value of it:"* - Question is: "How is that gettting automatically executed?".

Comment: This seems Wordpress related, is it? or similar? what does that `the_field()` function comprise of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `the_field()` is to blame as it probably has an `echo` statement within it.  You need to remove that.

Comment: Yes, you are so right! I have replaced it with `get_field()` which will no longer echo it out and it works great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In function `the_field()` replace `echo` with `return`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever the function **the_field** does involves echoing out the value passed to it.